# Xcode: [ERROR] Failed binding IPv4 listening socket: Address already in use (48)

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, ionic-v1

I have an ionic v1 project that I made updates to run properly on iPhone X but am getting errors in the simulator. I filed [this ticket](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v1/issues/356) on ionic-v1 forum but it has been 10+ days and haven't received any response so I am posting it here in hopes of getting some guidance.

Essentially when I run the older version of my project on iPhone simulator through XCode it comes up fine. However when I run the updated project on the same simulator I get a "Not found" error as below.

[image]

In the XCode log I see this error

```
[ERROR] Failed binding IPv4 listening socket: Address already in use (48)
```

This error is not present when I run the older version of the code that run successfully. I am not quite sure what socket is in use here and how to free that up. The updated code runs fine on a real device.

I am on Xcode 9.2 and iOS 10.13.2

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same issue with and found that an app spin off a built-in web server which serves www files. Thus when an app is run in emulator the server may conflict with another app on a host machine which also binds to 8080 port. In my case there was a dev web server which was run before.

You should check if some app binds to 8080 port on your machine. I suppose that two iOS emulator might conflict with each other as well.

My environment:

- ionic-angular: 3.9.2
- cordova: 8.0.0
- cordova-ios: 4.5.4
- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview: 1.1.16